# XDMP-TOOMANYPOSITIONS - Marklogic error

Tags: marklogic, cts-search

I am forming a query with many group of multiple or-queries,and queries- which is the 2nd parameter for the `cts:search()` function . But when I am using `cts:search()`  , I am getting **XDMP-TOOMANYPOSITIONS: error** . Can any one Please tell me the reason under what conditions . This error will occur ?

Comment: What is the full version string of MarkLogic Server?

Comment: Can you add the full query too?

Answer (score 0):

The docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/messages/XDMP-en#XDMP-TOOMANYPOSITIONS do not say much, but it means that query evaluation failed because there was too much position information. This is probably a server bug. Do not tune anything: none of the available settings affect this limit. If you aren't running the latest release, upgrade to the latest release and see if that helps. Otherwise you should contact support with details.

You could try the `unchecked` option to [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3asearch) - but that only works if this particular query does not really need to use position data. It's an easy test and it would confirm the nature of the problem.

If you can post the full query, someone might see a way to restructure it to work around the problem.

Another potential workaround is to turn off position indexes entirely: word-positions, element-word-positions, etc. However you probably had a good reason to turn them on in the first place.